# Should i publish my android app under creative common sharealike license or not? And how?

Tags: creative-commons

I am developing one android application in which I am using images licensed under creative common shared alike license(CC BY SA). license is saying "If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original." and must give attribution to work.

Thing is that I am using images as it is, no modification in images. So I am really confused in whether giving attribution to work is enough for me or should I distribute my work under same license and if it is how in case of Android app.

Specially I am really confused with build upon the material in license statement.

Help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you could have used any image in your application and you just choose these ones. If that is the case, your application and the images are separate works as far as copyrights are concerned.

This means that you can use any license you like for the code of your application, but the images need to stay under the CC BY-SA license.

Comment: i have given link to CC BY SA license below images i have used. is that enough or something else need to do ?

Comment: @Rhishikeshchogale, just mentioning the license is not enough for satisfying the attribution requirements. See https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Best_practices_for_attribution for how it is recommended to give attribution.

Comment: sure i formatted attribution like "Photo by licenced under CC BY 2.0" in which photo links to original photo page, by links to Author's profile page and CC BY 2.0 links to creative common license page. now as per good practices i am changing "by" to "Author name" where ever i have used images under CC. i hope this will work even for CC BY SA also where i have used images as it is from license, no modification in images.

Comment: @Rhishikeshchogale, the SA part of the license doesn't really have any effect if you are using the images unmodified. It basically says that you can't change the license when you *do* modify the image.